# I can"t decrypt in esp8266 nodemcu the string encrypted in PHP

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I was trying to sent encrypted info from server to ESP8266 wis nodemcu firmware.
But I can't decode it. The result is wrong.
Then I tested same string-key-metod encryption in PHP and NodeMCU. The result is different. 
???
Here is my test scripts.
PHP:

```
$data = "abc";

$key = "1234567812345678";

$b64enc = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-128-CBC', $key));

echo $b64enc;
```

The result is  **dWNTTDVSL2pRaWdRMWR4enNXaTJrZz09**

IN NodeMCU ESP8266:

```
key = "1234567812345678"

data = "abc"

b64enc = crypto.toBase64(crypto.encrypt("AES-CBC", key, data))

print(b64enc)
```

Node MCU result is  **2q7hfgajdCh6Ia5S7YpYww==**

????????????????????????????

It even looks different. 
I tested different options - all the same.
It's interesting if to make double encoding in NodeMCU:

```
print(crypto.toBase64(b64enc))
```

the result will look like in PHP:   **MnE3aGZnYWpkQ2g2SWE1UzdZcFl3dz09**   , but all the same different.

Any suggestion??

Comment: I solved problem. It looks like PHP openssl_encrypt() result is already in base64 code.  In NodeMCU I used encoder.fromBase64() and then crypto.decrypt().  In this case result is correct.

Comment: Maybe you could post this as an answer instead of comment. You could then accept your own answer thereby marking the question as resolved. Would help people like me who filter for open questions.